# Referencing Another App

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

What is the best way to reference another app in the visual query designer?

I am using the blog app and I created a second app to list the tags that are used in the main blog app. This way when the app goes to a detail page of a post, I can still have the tags listed on the website without the view changing automatically. I set up my blog tags app with a visual query that list all of the tags used in the main app. Everything was working fine in development.

The problem that I have run into is that when I move the app to a production site the AppId was different than the one I was currently using and development. Now, the tags app is showing an error and I am not able to get into the settings to change the app ID of the visual query to the proper one in order to get the information needed. Is there a better way that I should be handling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the right way to do it - your main issues is getting into the admin-ui when the template you have shows an error.

I suggest that you quickly rename your current template (so it's not used till you fix the bug) and create an empty template with the original name. This way you can go to the normal settings.

Another option is to switch into dnn-edit-mode, and use the black-dnn buttons to get to app-admin.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I ended up moving Tue app that was causing the error to a hidden page. This allowed the main blog app to start working again and I was able to use that app to go on and change the settings on the visual query on the tags app. After doing that, I moved the tags app back to the page it was on.